# How to return a value to caller which will updated in activity

Tags: android

I need to compute a paramater value in Activity and send back the result.

My code will look like this:

```
public String getMyValue(){
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWebView.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
return myValue;
}
```

Below is my MyWebView class

```
MyWebView extends Activity{
 protected void onCreate(){
 myValue = a+b;
 }
}
```

So, now if I call below code, I am getting null 'null' every time.

```
String a = getValue();
```

My question is how I have to return 'myValue' after it get updated in the activity.
Please let me know if there is other way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how I have to return 'myValue' after it get updated in
>   the activity.

For getting result from and back from Activity, you need to use `startActivityForResult()`. There are plenty of examples available on web so not including here.